# Find rectangles that contain point – Efficient Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Good afternoon.

**My situation:**

- In *two-dimensional space*.
- **Input**: a set of *rectangles* (*overlapping rectangles* too).

  - Rectangles coordinates are *integer type*.
  - There are not any constraints on rectangle-size and rectangle-location (only extent of integer).
  - No rectangles have width=0 or height=0.
- **I need to find**: all rectangles that contain entered *point* (with *integer* coordinates).

[image: Find rectangles that contain entered point.]

**Questions:**

- What is the efficient structure to keep rectangles?
- What alghorithm is efficient in this case?

  - And what algorithm is efficient only for adding rectangles without removing?

Thanks :-).

Comment: Are there any constraints on the location of the point, or on the size or position of the rectangles? Can the point be at any (floating-point) position, or only on a fixed grid? Can the rectangles have a minimum and maximum size?

Comment: Also related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583908/find-out-if-point-is-inside-one-of-n-possibly-overlapping-rectangles-in-less-t

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**R-Tree is the best data structure suitable for this use case.** R-trees are tree data structures used for spatial access methods, i.e., for indexing multi-dimensional information such as geographical coordinates, rectangles or polygons. The information of all rectangles can be stored in tree form so searching will be easy

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) page, [short ppt](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/454/jpei/slides/R-Tree.pdf) and the [research paper](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/papers/gutman-rtree.pdf) will help you understand the concept.

[image]

Comment: @Nanik have u tried it ? in case u face any issues, lemme know. i have coded it few yrs back and can help u.

Comment: @TejasP I'm working on it continuously. And thank you for the offer :-).

Comment: I was wondering about a segment tree.  Is there any reason an R tree would be better than a segment tree for this case?

Comment: From the wikipedia page: "Even if data can be fit in memory (or cached), the R-trees in most practical applications will usually provide performance advantages over naive check of all objects when the number of objects is more than few hundred or so. However, for in-memory applications, there are similar alternatives that can provide slightly better performance or be simpler to implement in practice." It sounds like R-tree might be overkill for in-memory or smaller data sets. Any idea which algorithms (other than brute force) might be better in those case?

Answer (score 3):

In java you can use shape.contains

But in general, assuming a rectangle is defined by (x,y,width,height) you do

if (pt.x >= x && pt.x <= x + width && pt.y >= y && pt.y <= y + height) ...

If you have all your rectangles in a collection you can iterate over the collection and find the ones that contain the point

Comment: Thanks :-). I write it in C++. I suppose thousand of rectangles and I don't want check each separately. Maybe some sorting structure.

Comment: Actually using this algorithm on thousands of rectangles shouldn't be a processing problem on todays computers. This math formula will execute very quickly. Trying to sort is somewhat problematic - how would you sort your rectangles?

Comment: I am thinking about some binary tree – sort by left-corner x-coordinate. Then I check only rectangles on left side of entered point x-coordinate. With balanced tree I can spare about half of checking time. Is it right? I am looking for efficient solution...

Comment: Yeah that should work. The amount of processing time that's saved is going to depend on your data. But assuming random points about half is right

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your set of rectangles may be dynamic ("...for adding rectangles..."). In this case  - 2D [Interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Higher_dimensions) could be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

A rectangle `(left, top, right, bottom)` contains a point `(x, y)` if `left < x < right` *and* `top < y < bottom` (assuming coordinates increase going downwards, which is the case with most hardware i've seen; if your coordinates increase going upwards, the more traditionally mathematical case, swap `top` and `bottom`).  You're not going to get much more efficient than that for the test.

If you consider a rectangle as "containing" a point if it's on the border as well, then replace all the `<`s with `<=`.

As for what to do with the collection of rectangles...i dunno.  I'd think a list sorted by the coordinates of the corners would do something, but i'm not really seeing much benefit to it...at most, you'd be cutting your list of stuff to check by half, on average (with the worst case still requiring checking everything). Half of a whole freaking lot can still be a whole lot.   :)

Comment: Thanks :-). I suppose thousand of rectangles and I don't want check each separately. I looking for some sorting structure to get only probable candidates.

Comment: Dunno if you'll find any, without precomputing the list with expected test points.  At which point you're not really saving anything unless you test the same few points a bunch of times.  Any algorithm that springs to mind would have false negatives on huge rectangles.

Comment: As you wrote... I am thinking about some binary tree – sort by left-corner x-coordinate. Then I check only rectangles on left side of entered point x-coordinate. With balanced tree I can spare about half of checking time. Is it right?

Comment: If your rectangles will be evenly distributed, possibly.  But of course, if you're checking a point at/near the right side, you're still gonna have to check everything.  Plus you have the cost of traversing and/or searching the tree.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution.

1. Define a grid on your plane.
2. Each cell maintains two lists: the rectangles that completely cover this cell and the rectangles that partially cover this cell.
3. On each insertion, put the ID of the target rectangle into all the involved cell lists.
4. On each query, locate the cell that contains the target point, output the completely cover list and run a scan on the partially cover list.

Comment: Makes for fast searching, once the grid is assembled.  But it seems like it could be outrageously slow to add a bunch of huge rectangles to it, depending on the resolution of the grid.

Comment: @cHao that's true, only ideal when the rectangles have similar size